Is my simpler proof correct?
Today we learned about partial limits of a sequence, i.e. a limit of some subsequence.
We wanted to prove a theorem where a sequence has a limit if every subsequence has the same limit (can be infinity or -infinity).
The teacher showed us a pretty long proof of this fact, but I came up with a much simpler proof:
Every subsequence has the same limit. I'll take the subsequence which is the same as the original sequence, but with the first term removed. It converges to that limit. Because we just changed one term, obviously this doesn't affect the limiting behavior of the original series, thus it also converges to that limit, Q.E.D.
This proof is much simpler and I was wondering why our teacher didn't just say that? I assume it's wrong but where's the flaw?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your proof is correct for the if direction. In fact, you do not even need to remove the first term because the sequence is a subsequence of its own.
But the whole statement of the theorem is that a sequence has a limit if and only if every subsequence has the same limit. I think the long proof that your teacher gave is for the only if direction.

As mentioned in the other answer, the proof of the ($\impliedby$) direction is trivial, for a sequence is a subsequence of itself.
The converse of the statement as written is also true, and its proof is a little more interesting. Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}+}$ that converges to $a$. Let $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ be a subsequence of $(a_n)$: note that $n_{k'} > n_k$ whenever $k' > k$. Consider any neighborhood $U$ of $a$; there exists some $N_U \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a_n \in U$ for each $n > N_U$. Now, there must be some $K_U \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n_{K_U} > N_U$. Then for any $k > K_U$, $n_k > n_{K_U} \implies n_k > N_U$, which means $a_{n_k} \in U$. This shows $(a_{n_k})$ converges to $a$, as desired. (Note that this is even true for pathological spaces where a sequence can converge to multiple limits: every subsequence converges to each of those limits!)

I think a much more interesting statement is the following: a sequence is convergent  iff there is a number $g$ such that every subsequence contains a subsequence convergent to $g.$
The direction $''\Rightarrow''$ is obvious.
For the $''\Leftarrow''$
direction, assume by contradiction that the sequence (say $x_n$) is not convergent. In particular it is not convergent to $g.$ Then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $N$ there is $n>N$ satisfying $|a_{n}-g|\ge \varepsilon.$ Thus for $N=1$ There is $j_1$ such that  $|a_{k_1}-g|\ge \varepsilon.$ Next for $N=k_1$ there is $k_2>k_1$ such that $|a_{k_2}-g|\ge \varepsilon.$ We continue that procedure and obtain an increasing sequence of indices  $k_n$ such that   $|a_{k_n}-g|\ge \varepsilon.$ Therefore the subsequence $a_{k_n}$ does not contain subsequence convergent to $g$ as all its terms are at the distance at least $\varepsilon$ from $g,$ a contradiction.

Can a subsequence not be finite? i.e. $1/n^2 \to \pi^2/6$, but ${1/s^2}$ for $s \in \text{Image}(f : [k] \to \mathbb N)$ does not converge to $\pi^2/6$ for any $f,k$ combo.

@Snared I do not understand your comment. Besides $1/n^2\to 0$ at least to my knowledge.

sorry I guess maybe I meant the partial sums, so ${ \sum_{s=1}^n 1/s^2, n \in \text{Image}(f: [k] \to \mathbb N)} \subset { \sum_{s=1}^n 1/s^2, n \in \mathbb N}$.

Certainly by increasing $k$ we are getting closer and closer to $\pi^2/6$, so we are converging in that sense that we can always find for any $\epsilon>0$ a $k \in \mathbb N$ where $|\pi^2/6 - S^{\text{parameterized with $f: [k] \mathbb N$ }}| < \epsilon$. But each error term is still positive, so finite subsequences won't give the desired property, only infinite ones. Often times when mentioning a sequence, what is meant is an infinite sequence, but I think the answer would be stronger if it were to say infinite sequence, as those who think of a sequence as infinite will still be ok, however,

There is a misundersting. In  OP we are talking about sequences not series. In case of series we consider subsequences of the  sequence of partial sums. Besides a subsequence of a $a_n$ is a sequence $a_{n_k}$ where $n_k\to \infty.$

Thank you. I remembered that there was a useful criterion with subsequences, but I couldn’t remember what it was.

I defined a sequence by taking partial sums

And any sequence can be thought of as a partial summation of some map.

Series are not a separate case, I have defined a sequence by using a series, but the object itself is a sequence, not a series.

If a sequence has a limit, then every subsequence has the same limit. If every subsequence has the same limit, then the sequence has this limit. This is what teacher proved to you.
You proved neither of these. You proved that if a sequence has a limit, then some particular subsequence has the same limit.

I think PortyMart would say they proved that if every subsequence has the same limit, then the sequence has this limit.
